# How can I detect an arbitrary SSD in a udev rule?

Tags: udev

I want to add a udev rule to set `sysctl -w vm.swappiness = 100` on machines where the boot partition is on a flash storage device.

My current system uses an NVMe card, which I can detect as `SUBSYSTEM="nvme"`, but I think (I don't have one available to check at the moment) that value for SATA SSDs is `"scsi"`, which is not SSD-specific. Actually, as I write this I dimly recall some manufacturer recently announced spinning disk NVMes for some niche usage, so that's not perfect either (though it'd be fine for my purposes).

How can I somewhat reliably detect the.. 'technology' of a storage device in a udev rule?

Comment: what's the "technology" you mean? Because SSDs *are* "flash storage devices"; and any "flash storage device" with an integrated flash abstraction layer is an SSD. So, where you want to make a difference, there is none.

Comment: @MarcusMüller Yes, exactly? But SCSI could be a spinning disk right? So unless you're saying SSDs (or HDDs) don't use `SUBSYSTEM="scsi"` as I said/assumed, I *can't* use 'scsi or nvme' to determine if it's flash. I'm not sure what isn't clear, but the goal is exactly to determine if it's a "flash storage device" which, yes, includes SSDs.

Comment: @MarcusMüller The only "difference I want to make" is that I'm stating that SSDs not on an NVMe card ("SATA SSDs") do not identify as "nvme", which is.. I would think obvious and uncontroversial.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check `/sys/block/*/queue/rotational` for finding out whether the kernel thinks it is a storage device with a rotating medium. This is independent of the subsystem.

And it is even available in `udev`:

```
udevadm info -a /dev/nvme0n1 | grep -F 'ATTR{queue/rotational}'
    ATTR{queue/rotational}=="0"
```

Comment: Nice, thanks, I'm tempted to accept this answer because I don't actually need it to be in a udev rule (in which I'm not sure how I would check the contents of this file?)... so, apologies to future searchers who do I suppose!

Comment: @OJFord It does work with udev, too; see my edit.

Comment: Perfect, thanks!